# Is there a php script to manage user registration and custom dashboard?

Tags: php

I'm not able to figure out a right script for this requirement.

What i'm looking for is a PHP script that allows users to register (example: Drupal/Joomla registration) and takes the registered users to a custom dashboard where I can add some custom fields and edit them from the backend.

Example:

User registers. (After the usual spam protection/email verification) the user would be presented with a dashboard where I (the admin) can manually edit fields such as 'Amount Deposited' Weekly File Download' and other such fields.

The only catch being that the information needs to be  unique to a user.

Hope i'm making sense?

Comment: Your needs sound rather specific, maybe you can't find a script because no such script is available. A bespoke route may be needed here.

Comment: Well I was actually hoping to avoid that.. if there is a script that could come any closer, customization would be a better option. All the scripts I look for are to do with member registration/billing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching on some PHP scripts repository (e.g. [Code Canyon](http://codecanyon.net/category/php-scripts) or [Binpress](http://binpress.com)) ?

Comment: Yep incl. hotscripts.. which is what led me to ask a question here, hopefully the developer community would have a better idea.

Comment: If everything fails, simply rent-a-coder who write that thing for you (services like vWorker or oDesk). Or simply - I can write such thing for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the the WoltLab Community Framweork is something for you:
http://www.woltlab.com/wcf/